# Why does my app icon not appear in one system function on iphone?

Tags: ios, iphone, appicon

It doesn't show when you double touch on the home button on iPhone 8 but it does on the simulator for iPhone 8.

Here are two screenshots of what works and what doesn't:

Working on simulator:
[image: phone 8 simulator image with working app icon]

Not working on device:
[image: iPhone 8 real device screenshot without working app icon]

It should be the yellow icon but instead is the empty target.

Answer (score 0):

Because I had been running it with the blank icon, it took time for the system to recognize the new icon.  All I had to do was wait and it is working now.